# xcode6 linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

My app runs fine on a real device, but when i'm trying to run it on a simulator it gives me this error. Can anyone help me understand what's this error is ?

> ld: in '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libextension.dylib', missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libextension.dylib (3 slices) for architecture x86_64
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Xcode cannot find a libextension.dylib file that has been built for the simulator architecture that you selected. Since the .dylib file should come with Xcode, I suspect a problem with the Xcode version that you have. Did you build the project by yourself, or download it?

You can try going into Preferences-> downloads and downoading the simulator components listed there.